# What's wrong with this vimscript function?

Tags: vim

I've tried creating a vim script that shows whitespaces when a keystroke is called but i get an error when calling the function. Here is the code:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8

let s:showingWhiteSpaces=0
function! ShowWhiteSpace()
  if s:showingWhiteSpaces
    set nolist
    noh
    let s:showingWhiteSpaces=0
    echo "we are here1"
  else
    set list
    highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=darkgreen
    :match ExtraWhitespace /\S\zs\s\+$
    let s:showingWhiteSpaces=1
    echo "we are here2"
  endif
endfunction
```

also the _vimrc is:

```
set nocompatible                " choose no compatibility with legacy vi
syntax enable
set encoding=utf-8
set showcmd                     " display incomplete commands
filetype plugin indent on       " load file type plugins + indentation

"" Whitespace
set nowrap                      " don't wrap lines
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2      " a tab is two spaces (or set this to 4)
set expandtab                   " use spaces, not tabs (optional)
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " backspace through everything in insert mode

"" Searching
set hlsearch                    " highlight matches
set incsearch                   " incremental searching
set ignorecase                  " searches are case insensitive...
set smartcase                   " ... unless they contain at least one capital letter

" Shortcut to rapidly toggle `set list`
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬

nnoremap <leader>l call ShowWhiteSpace()<CR>

colors monokai

" Try the following if your GUI uses a dark background.
:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=darkgreen
```

When trying the hotkey \l nothing happens, and when calling the function from normal mode with :call ShowWhiteSpace(), the following error occurs:

```
E475: Invalid argument: /\S\zs\s\+$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
match ExtraWhitespace /\S\zs\s\+$/
```

#### update : to fix the mapping

```
nnoremap <leader>l :call ShowWhiteSpace()<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now, if i call it from the "command line", however the hotkey still doesn't do anything. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @AdrianSuciu check answer, you need the `:` in mapping